# can you view/tail the server log rails app on travis ci

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, selenium, capybara, travis-ci

I have Rails app which has an Rspec feature with selenium  that always passes locally and periodically fails on travis. It fails on click_link("my link"), with a Net::ReadTimeout: error.  The stack trace isn't all that helpful and It'd be nice if there was a way to tail the log  (tail -f log/test.log), so see if that's helpful...or at least view the log output.  Is this possible using travis ci?  I'm already waiting for ajax to finish, which suggests something external, so ultimately I'm trying to find out what request it's getting hung up on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can cat the logs to the console as the last step of your test task, or you can use Travis' artifact option to get them uploaded to S3 - see http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/uploading-artifacts/